# Error: A valid React element (or null) must be returned (Checked Return() and Render())

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null, return, render

I have been getting the following error after refactoring some code...

```
PartnersIteration.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be 
returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other 
invalid object.
```

Everything that I have read so far has told me to look at the syntax of my return and render functions. I have checked it all, I just dont see where the error is coming from! Any chance someone could point it out to me? Thanks!

PS. I have put debuggers in all over the place and have access to all of my declared variables, from state, props or otherwise defined locally in my `render()` function

```
render() {
  let newAllPartners = this.props.newAllPartners;
  let dynamicPartnerList = this.state.dynamicPartnerList;
  let count = this.state.count;
  let lastLetter = this.props.lastLetter;
  let firstLetter;
  let randomNumber;

if(newAllPartners != null && newAllPartners != undefined && (Object.keys(newAllPartners).length != 0)){
  dynamicPartnerList.map(function(object) {
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (300-10000 + 1) + 1000);

    if(object.name != undefined) {
      firstLetter = object.name.charAt(0);

      if(firstLetter === lastLetter) {
        firstLetter = '';
        showImage(object.id, object.urlPicture);

        return(
          <tbody>
            <tr className="row clickable" key={object.id} onClick={() => this.rowClick(object.id)}>
              <td>
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr className="row">
                      <td className="child col s4 m3 l2">
                        <img id={object.id}  height="56px" />
                      </td>
                      <td className="col s8 m9 l10">
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td className="columnwithTitleSubtile">
                                <p className="producerName">{object.name}</p>
                                <p className="subtitle">{object.countSIF} {<FormattedMessage id="navbar.slaughterhouses"/>}</p>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        )
      }

      else {
      lastLetter = firstLetter;
      return(
        <tbody>
          <tr key={randomNumber}>
            <td className="firstLetter">{firstLetter}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        )
      }
    }

    else {
      return(
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              {<FormattedMessage id="msgempty.default"/>}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      )
    }
  })
}
```

}

Comment: Not all branches of execution return something...

Comment: Ok, nice catch guys. Unfortunately, I implemented that correction but am still getting the same error. I ended up getting rid of the first `if` before my `.map` function. So now, it just goes straight to the map function without the conditional. Now, I have 2 `if` and 2 `else`

Comment: A note on your code. The component is way too big and difficult to read. its not modular at all. Also you have too much logic in your render and you shouldn't have if statements in if statements like this. You should set up a consistent return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you all else..if statements and the main problem - you don't return anything in `render`. You have returns in `map`, but you need to return your map too:

```
return <div>{dynamicPartnerList.map(function (object) {...})} </div>
```

Comment: Nice! I totally forgot to return the `.map` function. I had refactored this file from a `const` to a stateful component and must have missed that part. Thanks! Also, the `if/else` discrepancy was an an issue as well.

Answer (score 4):

You have 3 `if` statements and only 2 `else`'s. this means not all condition blocks returns a valid react object.
It seems like the first `if` condition lacks an `else` block, so i added one for you to check:

```
if (newAllPartners != null && newAllPartners != undefined && (Object.keys(newAllPartners).length != 0)) {
    dynamicPartnerList.map(function (object) {
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (300 - 10000 + 1) + 1000);

        if (object.name != undefined) {
            firstLetter = object.name.charAt(0);

            if (firstLetter === lastLetter) {
                firstLetter = '';
                showImage(object.id, object.urlPicture);

                return (
                    <tbody>
                        <tr className="row clickable" key={object.id} onClick={() => this.rowClick(object.id)}>
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr className="row">
                                            <td className="child col s4 m3 l2">
                                                <img id={object.id} height="56px" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td className="col s8 m9 l10">
                                                <table>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td className="columnwithTitleSubtile">
                                                                <p className="producerName">{object.name}</p>
                                                                <p className="subtitle">{object.countSIF} {<FormattedMessage id="navbar.slaughterhouses" />}</p>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                )
            }

            else {
                lastLetter = firstLetter;
                return (
                    <tbody>
                        <tr key={randomNumber}>
                            <td className="firstLetter">{firstLetter}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                )
            }
        }

        else {
            return (
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {<FormattedMessage id="msgempty.default" />}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            )
        }
    })
} 
else{ // this was missing
    return <tbody></tbody>
}
```